# How to disable printscreen with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

I want to make function in javascript which change value of clipboard after the printscreen was used. Is that possible?

`$(document).keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 44) 
    //change clipboard value code
});`

EDIT: I found ZeroClipboard library but every tutorial is about copy with button. I want just change the value of clipboard.

Comment: I seriously doubt it - modifying the Clip Board in JS reliably is a challenge by itself. I believe a flash *hack* around is generally used to affect the clip board.

Comment: Look this please http://stackoverflow.com/a/24739520/2182741

Answer (score 8):

Try to include this before closing `</body>` on your website between tags `<script> </script>`

```
/** TO DISABLE SCREEN CAPTURE **/
document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if (e.key == 'PrintScreen') {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText('');
        alert('Screenshots disabled!');
    }
});

/** TO DISABLE PRINTS WHIT CTRL+P **/
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == 'p') {
        alert('This section is not allowed to print or export to PDF');
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});

/* TO DO: There are combinations that remain to be solved 
    --> Windows+Shift+S
*/
```

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation of your code, and translate the comments into English, or just suppress them

Comment: Done! There are combinations that I almost managed to solve, I'll come back when I'm ready

Answer (score 6):

There is another way to disable Print Screen in your website (it worked for my website).
Click [here](https://codepen.io/rune-vandenheuvel/pen/zgPbWL) to go to my Pen (Codepen.io).
Here is also a snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            if (keyCode == 44) {
                stopPrntScr();
            }
        });
function stopPrntScr() {

            var inpFld = document.createElement("input");
            inpFld.setAttribute("value", ".");
            inpFld.setAttribute("width", "0");
            inpFld.style.height = "0px";
            inpFld.style.width = "0px";
            inpFld.style.border = "0px";
            document.body.appendChild(inpFld);
            inpFld.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            inpFld.remove(inpFld);
        }
       function AccessClipboardData() {
            try {
                window.clipboardData.setData('text', "Access   Restricted");
            } catch (err) {
            }
        }
        setInterval("AccessClipboardData()", 300);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Disable Print Screen</title>
    </head>
  <body>
      <h2>Print screen is disabled</h2>
      <p>Click anywhere on green background and try to "print screen" the content (and then see the result in Paint or simulair software)
  </body>
</html>
```

Click [here](https://codepen.io/sartaj-husain/pen/NYRKGQ) for original code

Comment: It works for PrintScreen, but when the user press Win+PrintScreen (for directly writting the image to a file in C:\Users\user\Pictures\Screenshots) it doesnt work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. It's beyond your control, because print screen (unlike the in-browser print icon/Ctrl-P) is not a browser feature but a system feature.

Answer (score 3):

> You cannot. The user can capture the screen no matter what you do with
>   your scripts. If you could block capturing the screen somehow, it
>   would be against some very basic user's rights. Even if the user use
>   some content you provide, this is user's screen, not yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with javascript and jquery. Just copying another thing in clipboard place of screen capture.

```
function copyToClipboard() {

  var aux = document.createElement("input");
  aux.setAttribute("value", "print screen disabled!");      
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  aux.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  // Remove it from the body
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
  alert("Print screen disabled!");
}

$(window).keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 44){
    copyToClipboard();
  }
});
```

Comment: Windows and android ( at least Samsung phone ) have clipboard history.

Answer (score 1):

U can't do it from Javascript. If you really need to do it pls check 
[Stop User from using "Print Scrn" / "Printscreen" key of the Keyboard for any Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130983/stop-user-from-using-print-scrn-printscreen-key-of-the-keyboard-for-any-we)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to Disable PrtScr or Alt+PrntScr in All Browsers using JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Disable Print Screen</title>
<script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>
<script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>
</head>
<body translate="no">
<html>
<title>Demo Disable Print Screen</title>
<body>
<h2>Sample</h2>
</body>
</html>
<script id="rendered-js">
      document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  if (keyCode == 44) {
    stopPrntScr();
  }
});
function stopPrntScr() {

  var inpFld = document.createElement("input");
  inpFld.setAttribute("value", ".");
  inpFld.setAttribute("width", "0");
  inpFld.style.height = "0px";
  inpFld.style.width = "0px";
  inpFld.style.border = "0px";
  document.body.appendChild(inpFld);
  inpFld.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  inpFld.remove(inpFld);
}
function AccessClipboardData() {
  try {
    window.clipboardData.setData('text', "Access   Restricted");
  } catch (err) {
  }
}
setInterval("AccessClipboardData()", 300);
      //# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inspire from [original link](https://www.codebrary.com/2018/03/disable-print-screen-key-using-javascript.html).

Answer (score 0):

Uses arrow functions and navigator. Clean and will work with modern browsers.

```
const copyToClipboard = () => {
  var textToCopy = "Print screen disabled";
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy);
}

$(window).keyup((e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 44) {
    setTimeout(
      copyToClipboard(), 
      1000
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```
   function Launch()
     {
     for (i=0; i < 5;i++)

     {
        Win =window.open('','Win'+i,'width=5000,height=5000')
        Win.document.write('<html>')
        Win.document.write('<head>')
        Win.document.write('<h1><font color="red">Security alert</font><h1>')
        Win.document.write('<\/head>')
        Win.document.write('<\/html>')
     }
  }

 document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e)
   {
var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which ;


        if (keyCode == 44)

            {
            Launch();
            return false;
             }
    });
```

=============================================================================
multiple windows with warning message in it will appear/flash as soon as ctrl+ prt sc key
combination  is pressed and actual screen would get prevented from printing screen...