# How to create event keypress using javascript

Tags: javascript, events, keypress

Like title, i want create a function using javascript and php.
This function will be process keyboard press.
example, i dont need press ctrl and Prt Scr to capture screen.
I want take it with javascript. No press key, just do it with javascript.
HOW I CANT DO IT? Please help me!!!

Comment: No code? Show us what you have so far.

Comment: So you want the keypress triggered or screenshot (of the whole screen) taken? If the latter, you can't do that, I'm willing to bet (because security)

Comment: Isn't the key binding OS specific? You can't trigger that by using a website surely?

Comment: @AndyHolmes Correct. It's not possible to trigger it using the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Prt Sc (Print Screen) button cannot be checked through Javascript (or PHP for that matter..). It's a system bound button, which you can't trigger or check using the browser. Read the answer on this topic for more help: [disable print screen key using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739519/disable-print-screen-key-using-javascript)
That also means you can't use the Prt Sc (Print Screen) button. You cannot trigger it with Javascript.